# How to set up dependencies to get access to the ActivityRecognition API?

Tags: java, android, activity-recognition

According to this link ([Detect when users start ou end an activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions)), I have added the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0` library to use the `ActivityRecognition` API in my app. The problem is that Android Studio, despite this, doesn't find the definition for `ActivityTransition` or `DetectedActivity` classes.

Does anyone know what I should add to be able to use these classes?

Edit : as found somewhere in the Android doc, I have already added the following dependencies :

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:18.0.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0'
```

Comment: What happens if you also add a direct dependency to the transition api? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/transition

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no change...

Comment: Added the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0` dependency and both classes are now recognized!